# Joomla search module with predefined suggestions

Tags: search, joomla

I want to create one search module in joomla exactly as in zomato.com website.It has predefined search suggestions.Suggestions will appear before typing.Can anyone help me??..I am a beginner in Joomla.

Comment: You have to try something first in order to help you improve it. Are you beginner with joomla or with php / mysql / ajax / jquery too?

Comment: try looking for a search component that support this. If you can't, you'll have to code a custom javascript modal thing.

Comment: I am beginner in Joomla.But I have experience in php/mysql/ajax/jquery.So I have to create a custom search module.right?

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)